# Javascript Event on iOS status bar tap

Tags: javascript, ios, events, statusbar

Normally, if you tap on the status bar in iOS, the currently shown page/list automatically scrolls to the top. I want to use this behavior in my website, so if the user taps the status bar, the page scrolls to the top. The problem I'm having is the following: The list is just a `div` element with `overflow-y:scroll`, so if the status bar is tapped, it won't scroll.

My idea was to make the scrolling in javascript with `scrollTo(0)`, but I need to know when the status bar is tapped. Is there an event for this? Or even a completely different approach (tell Safari what the main

Answer (score -1):

Yes there are touch events now in the API [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch/#) is a site that might be helpful. You can capture events for touch start, move and end (what you probably want). Most of these events are now applicable to most devices however since you are using IOS you'll be safe.

Comment: This won't work, as the statusbar tap is caught by iOS. You won't get a touch event.